# Why is Position function returing empty list for existing numbers in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
x = Table[i, {i, 4.24, 159.76, 3.24}]
```

> {4.24, 7.48, 10.72, 13.96, 17.2, 20.44, 23.68, 26.92, 30.16, 33.4,
>   36.64, 39.88, 43.12, 46.36, 49.6, 52.84, 56.08, 59.32, 62.56, 65.8,69.04, 72.28, 75.52, 78.76, 82., 85.24, 88.48, 91.72, 94.96, 98.2,101.44, 104.68, 107.92,111.16, 114.4, 117.64, 120.88, 124.12,127.36, 130.6, 133.84, 137.08, 140.32, 143.56, 146.8, 150.04, 153.28,156.52, 159.76};

but when I'm executing:

```
Table[Position[x, i], {i, 4.24, 159.76, 3.24}]
```

I am getting the following output:

> {{{1}}, {{2}}, {{3}}, {{4}}, {{5}}, {{6}}, {{7}}, {{8}}, {{9}},{{10}}, {}, {{12}}, {{13}}, {}, {{15}}, {{16}}, {{17}}, {{18}}, {},{{20}}, {{21}}, {{22}}, {{23}}, {{24}}, {{25}}, {{26}}, {{27}},{{28}}, {{29}}, {{30}}, {}, {{32}}, {{33}}, {}, {{35}}, {{36}},{{37}}, {{38}}, {{39}}, {{40}}, {{41}}, {{42}}, {{43}}, {}, {{45}},{{46}}, {{47}}, {{48}}, {{49}}};

Now what I am not understanding is why am I getting those empty lists, all numbers are already present in x, but still for some of them (e.g. 36.44) the Position function returns an empty list). It will be great if someone could help me regarding this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with ver. 11.1.1 on win 10 home 64-bit, whats your OS

Comment: same for me on win 10 and mathematica 10.3. did you try restarting the kernel?

Comment: same here on 11.1.1 for Linux x86

Comment: same for me Win7, Mma 11.1.1. However, I guess that since the list consists of real numbers, rather than of integers, some of these numbers may differ from one another by the machine precision value, and, thus, be unequal.

Comment: Not reproducible with V11.1.1 on OS X 10.10.2 either. Like @AlexeiBoulbitch, I think this is likely a numerics problem with older versions that has been corrected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I cannot reproduce the problem the user is experiencing